# createSlice in React redux toolkit is not showing intellisense in VS CODE

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

When i type "createSlice" it is not showing any intellisense in VS CODE. [create slice VS code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GTxW.png)

Answer (score 0):

You never actually imported the `createSlice` function.

Your file needs an appropriate import statement:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
```

Comment: I want to import createSlice automatically by VS CODE.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure two things:

1. Did you import it??? Like this :

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
```

2. Are you sure that reac-toolkit is installed? Check your Json file, if not then do this:

```
npm install @reduxjs/toolkit ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution and it worked. Add an empty jsconfig.js file on the root folder then it will show createSlice intellisense automatically.